# Race condition with Dispatcher.Invoke

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a WritableBitmap and I want to get its dimensions. Because the object is owned by another thread, we have to go through the Dispatcher. I've tried this:

```
int targetPixelWidth = 0;
int targetPixelHeight = 0;

writeableBitmap.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    targetPixelWidth = writeableBitmap.PixelWidth;
    targetPixelHeight = writeableBitmap.PixelHeight;
}));

// Do something with targetPixelWidth and targetPixelHeight
```

However, this sometimes fails: the values often remained 0, even though the real values are different.

Thinking it might be a threading issue, I changed the code as follows:

```
var bitmapInfo = (Tuple<int, int>)writeableBitmap.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Func<Tuple<int, int>>(
   () => Tuple.Create(writeableBitmap.PixelWidth, writeableBitmap.PixelHeight)
));

Debug.Assert(bitmapInfo != null, "Obviously, this should pass.");

targetPixelWidth = bitmapInfo.Item1;
targetPixelHeight = bitmapInfo.Item2;

// Do something with targetPixelWidth and targetPixelHeight
```

But now, `bitmapInfo` is sometimes null. Which is strange, because (according to the documentation) `Invoke` should only return null when the delegate has no return value, which it obviously does in this case. I've even `Debug.Assert`ed the return value of `Tuple.Create`, and it was never null.

What am I missing here? What causes this race condition, and what can I do about it?

Comment: try ()=> return new Tuple.Create(writeableBitmap.PixelWidth, writeableBitmap.PixelHeight);

Comment: I did; didn't make a difference, unfortunately.

Comment: did you try putting the Debug.Assert or logging inside the lambda expresion?

Comment: @makc Yep, that's what I meant when I said that I `Debug.Assert`ed the `Tuple.Create`. Obviously I had to explicitly type `return` for that one, as you suggested above, or it wouldn't compile. I left it out, here, for brevity.

Comment: can you please add the creation code of writeableBitmap and its binding, maybe that will help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, although I don't know why:

```
ManualResetEventSlim mre = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);

int targetPixelWidth = 0;
int targetPixelHeight = 0;

writeableBitmap.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    try {
        targetPixelWidth = writeableBitmap.PixelWidth;
        targetPixelHeight = writeableBitmap.PixelHeight;
    }
    finally {
        mre.Set();
    }
}));

mre.Wait();
// Do something with targetPixelWidth and targetPixelHeight
```

Somebody (who posted an answer to this question but later removed it), suggested that `Invoke` is synchronous on the GUI thread, not on the thread that calls `Invoke`. If that's true, that would explain why this works. However, [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc647509%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), the books [[1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672331195), [2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672330334)] and little toy programs attempting to reproduce this problem, all suggest that this is not the case; `Invoke` should be synchronous on the calling thread.

I haven't been able to come up with a real explanation; if someone has one, I'm all ears :).

**EDIT** Replaced my original, somewhat rambling answer with something more coherent.

Comment: the documentation states that `Invoke is a synchronous operation; therefore, control will not return to the calling object until after the callback return` and that return valu is `the return value from the delegate being invoked or null if the delegate has no return value.`
can you quote the documentation which states that its sync only on UI thread, thanks

Comment: "Executes the specified delegate with the specified arguments **synchronously on the thread the Dispatcher is associated with**"
(emphasis mine).
It does seem to conflict with the piece of documentation you quote. Still, reality also seems to conflict with it... :(

Comment: I think I'll have to test it to believe, it solves your issue so +1

Comment: I didn't believe it at first, either. Also, it's still entirely possible that my explanation is completely wrong, even though it does work :). However, this is how I interpret what the original answerer said.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

sorry for given the wrong answer.

It seems that you want to get the dependency property of WriteableBitmap which lives in gui thread from another thread.

you can try this:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(100, 100, 300, 300, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null);
        _image.Source = writeableBitmap;

        new Thread(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                var pixelHeigth = (Int32)writeableBitmap.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                                                     DispatcherPriority.Background,
                                                    (DispatcherOperationCallback)(arg => ((WriteableBitmap)arg).PixelHeight), writeableBitmap);
                Debug.Print("PixelHeight:" + pixelHeigth);

            }).Start();

    }
```

I just tried, it works well.

Comment: How is accessing the underlying dependency property different from just calling the 'normal' accessor in this case?

Comment: @jqno sorry to given the wrong answer, i just edited the answer

Comment: I'm not sure if it was the wrong answer, I just didn't understand it :). I'll try it out tomorrow, to see if it works. (On my way home now.) Thanks!

Comment: @jqno the dependency property can only be accessed by its owner thread which is usually the gui thread. so just as the code you post, using Dispatcher.Invoke is the right way. but i don't know why your code is now working.  maybe the writeableBitmap is not initialized yet. so use DispatcherPriority.Background to let the Invoke be called after writeableBitmap initialization may be work.

Comment: That makes sense! I'll try it out tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: Nope, that wasn't it, sadly.